# Module not found: Can't resolve '/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm facing an error in my React Native project with the following message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/SharedEventEmitter.js:18
Module not found: Can't resolve '/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter'
```

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

- I've checked my project's dependencies, and I have the required versions of React Native and the `@react-native-firebase/app` package.
- I've tried clearing the npm cache and rebuilding the project, but the error persists.
- I've ensured that I have imported and initialized Firebase correctly in my project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to same problems (a path change in the library) that are explained in these issues, take a look

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/386

and this

https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework/issues/68